# Some help understanding Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am writing a cypher query to combine information into one result for my site. When I put it all together in one Cypher group all the results come as 5:

```
MATCH (p:Person{username:"wkolcz"})
MATCH(p)-[]->(um:Meetup{status:"Accepted"})
WHERE toInt(um.meet_date) >= 1444827367
MATCH(p)-[]->(pm:Meetup{status:"Accepted"})
WHERE toInt(pm.meet_date) <= 1444827367
MATCH (p)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group)
RETURN count(um) as upcoming, count(pm) as past_meetups, count(g) as group_total
```

But when I break them into individual queries and output the result, they are correct. What am I missing? Thanks!

```
MATCH (p:Person{username:"wkolcz"})
MATCH(p)-[]->(pm:Meetup{status:"Accepted"})
WHERE toInt(pm.meet_date) <= 1444827367
RETURN count(pm) as past_meetups
```

The result is 1 (correct)

```
MATCH (p:Person{username:"wkolcz"})
MATCH(p)-[]->(um:Meetup{status:"Accepted"})
WHERE toInt(um.meet_date) >= 1444827367
RETURN count(um) as upcoming
```

The result is 1 (correct)

```
MATCH (p:Person{username:"wkolcz"})
MATCH (p)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group)
RETURN count(g) as group_total
```

The result is 5 (correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that all of your `MATCH`es together are forming one big subgraph pattern match and Neo4j is matching on all of the permutations that it can find of those matches.  There might be a better solution, but one way to get around this it to simply do one match at a time and pass through the results with `WITH`:

```
MATCH (p:Person {username:"wkolcz"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[]->(um:Meetup {status:"Accepted"})
WHERE toInt(um.meet_date) >= 1444827367
WITH p, count(um) as upcoming

OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[]->(pm:Meetup {status:"Accepted"})
WHERE toInt(pm.meet_date) <= 1444827367
WITH p, upcoming, count(pm) as past_meetups

OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group)
RETURN upcoming, past_meetups, count(g) as group_total
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have more luck using `OPTIONAL MATCH`:

```
MATCH (p:Person {username:"wkolcz"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[]->(um:Meetup {status:"Accepted"})
WHERE toInt(um.meet_date) >= 1444827367
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[]->(pm:Meetup {status:"Accepted"})
WHERE toInt(pm.meet_date) <= 1444827367
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group)
RETURN count(um) as upcoming, count(pm) as past_meetups, count(g) as group_total
```

This should also give you entries where the `count()` is zero, which `MATCH` doesn't allow for.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Actually I started with that and still comes up with the same results with all 5's

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by all 5s...  Could you provide a setup script?  Or maybe setup an example here http://neo4j-console-22.herokuapp.com/ with the Share button?

Comment: The results for all three items is 5. So the output is 5 upcoming, 5 past_meetups, and 5 group_total. Only the group count should be 5, in the database there is only 1 past_meetup and 1 upcoming meetup. It appears that it takes the result for the last items and assigns it to all the variables.